# In Gizmos, does blind picking from the energy dispenser count as a "Pick" action?

Tags: gizmos

In the board game Gizmos, some cards have triggers that are activated when you pick a particular color. Do these triggers only get activated when the player picks from the Energy Row? Or are they triggered if the player picks blindly from the dispenser as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not count as a "pick". From the rulebook, page 3:

> IMPORTANT: Some abilities may let you draw a random Energy ( ). **This is
>   not a Pick Action.** In those cases, you don’t take from the Energy Row. Instead, you
>   draw blindly from the top of the Dispenser

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get energy marbles: pick, and draw. Pick is represented by a hand with two fingers making a pinching motion. Draw is represented by a horizontal bar with a question mark in a circle above it. To pick is to take a marble from the Energy Row. You get to take the color of your choice (among the ones available in the Energy Row). To draw is to take one from the hopper. You do not get to know what color you're getting until you draw.

A card will have a symbol that says what triggers it. If it's the hand symbol, it's triggered only by picking.